# Using customResource to register RDS layer to opsworks stack

Tags: json, aws-opsworks, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloudformation template that creates a stack, layers and applications. The applications have a database configuration as `Datasources` :

```
"AdminApp": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::App",
      "Properties": {
        "AppSource" : {
          "Type" : "git",
          "Url" : "git://github.com:myrepo/adminapp.git",
          "Revision" : "master"
        },
        "DataSources":[{
          "Arn" : { "Ref" : "RegisterRDStoStack" },
          "DatabaseName" : "fadmin",
          "Type" : "RdsDbInstance"
        }],
        "Description": "Administration",
        "Name" : "admin-api",
        "Shortname" : "admin_api",
        "StackId" : {"Ref": "Stack"},
        "Type" : "php"
      }
    },
```

The database in the property Datasources sould be registered first to the stack so that the applications can have access to it.
As AWS didn't implement yet the creation of an RDS layer in the opsworks stack by using Cloudformation, so I created a CustomResource as a workaround  :

```
"RegisterRDStoStack" : {
  "Type": "Custom::RDSLayer",
  "Version" : "1.0",
  "Properties" : {
    "ServiceToken": {"Ref" : "RDSInstanceARN"},
    "StackId" : {"Ref" : "Stack" },
    "User" : {"Ref" : "UserDB" },
    "Password" : {"Ref" : "PasswordDB" }
  }
},
```

When testing the template I get this error :

```
CREATE_FAILED   Custom::RDSLayer    RegisterRDStoStack  Invalid service token
```

So it seems that there is an error, but don't know what exactly. I properly provided the ARN of the database. What Am I supposed to do to make this work please? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the ARN of the Lambda function (e.g., `{"Ref": "MyLambdaFunction"}`) as the `ServiceToken` parameter for a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html). See the documentation for [`ServiceToken`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html#cfn-customresource-servicetoken):

> The service token that was given to the template developer by the service provider to access the service, such as an Amazon SNS topic ARN or Lambda function ARN. The service token must be from the same region in which you are creating the stack.

Comment: which lambda function? To do what?

Comment: @Cloudgls The Lambda function containing the custom provisioning logic you wish to invoke from your Custom Resource. To do whatever it is you want to do with your Custom Resource.